# Render from pre-calculated data set?

Tags: image, video, webgl

I made a physics simulator and have a pre-calculated data set of point positions for each time step.  Can I programmatically render each frame individually with the data, output to an image with blender and stitch it into a video (maybe blender does both steps), or maybe an animation controlled with a slider?

Basically, I'm trying to serve up the data visually via a web page.  Background servers already compiled the data.  I am either looking to have a server use blender to take the data and render to a video file, or send the data to the client through the page and use blender to render it on the fly on their machines while they use a slider to navigate the time steps.

I don't need too many details right now, just a high level if it's possible before I jump headlong into it.  Any details on how would be icing.

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's definitely possible. You will want to look into Python scripting to accomplish this. The general workflow might look like this:

1. Build a Blender scene that kind of resembles what you want.
2. Write python script to ingest your data, and apply the data onto the scene you already built. Do you want your data to drive the location/position/size of objects? Or something more complicated?
3. Render.

Comment: Yes, the idea is that the data will drive the positions/sizes/quantity of objects.  Python is newish to me so I'll lurk the forums for some good examples of individual tasks. :)

Answer (score 0):

One option is to run blender in the background (ie, without a gui). This lets it run as part of a shell script.  This would be good if you want to render it on the fly when a page is requested.  The [official documentation](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Reference/Command_Line) explains more options than I can give here.  Look at scripting under the render options.  It will give you the most flexibility.

Comment: Is scripting or compiling/importing a library more commonly used/supported by the community?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, but python scripting is by far the most common way to modify blender.  Any of the python libraries can be used with it.